# How to implement a interface method with <S extends T> Iterable<S>

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Mock implementation of the Spring class CrudRepository but I cannot find how to implement this method :

```
public <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable)
```

For example, I have this :

```
private class CrudRepositoryMock implements CrudRepository<String, String> {
  // works fine, the method is correctly overridden
  // method signature in interface : public <S extends T> S save(S s)
  @Override
  public String save(String s) {
    return null;
  }

  // does not work, IntelliJ tells me that the method does not override 
  // from the superclass
  // method signature in interface : 
  // <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable)
  @Override
  public Iterable<String> save(Iterable<String> iterable) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The other methods are overridden successfully. I just don't know what I should write to correctly override the method with the Iterable.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not meant to implement this interface yourself. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes it was just a bad example. I have an interface that extends PagingAndSortingRepository with my custom class (not a String) and I want to mock this interface implementation for unit testing.

Comment: You should use `Mockito` or something to stub behavior. Don't write your own implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that S is a type parameter declared by the method, so `Iterable<S extends String>` is not `Iterable<String>`, one allows subtypes of String ( which is not a good example) where the latter doesn't,

The right override that adheres to the interface would be

```
@Override
public <S extends String> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. My code doesn't really use String but a custom class, I just wrote this small example here and I chose badly, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That is because since the parameter is `S extends T`, the `Iterable` needs a `S extends String`, and `String` is not sufficient.

Consider this: If `MyString extends String`, you should be allowed to call `save(Iterable<MyString>)` and return a `Iterable<MyString>`, which is incompatible with `Iterable<String>`.

You need to keep the generic `S`:

```
@Override
public <S extends String> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Eclipse IDE's "Override/Implement Methods" shortcut, I get

```
@Override
public <S extends String> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

However, this generates a warning; namely, that `String` is final and cannot be extended. You can pass in `String` object, but by convention `final` classes should not be used by generics.

Comment: Thanks. This was just meant as an example. In my real code, I have a custom class called User and not String. I should have written the correct code.

Comment: No problem :P In that case, it should work with no warnings.